# Find all positive reals $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $x + y + z = 6$, $1/x +1/y+1/z =2 - 4/xyz$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all positive reals $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x + y + z = 6\\\\
\dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{1}{y} + \dfrac{1}{z} = 2 - \dfrac{4}{xyz}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Try using symmetry.

Comment: Could this be solved using a high-school Systems-of-Equations approach? Substitution or elimination?

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=xyz.$

$AM-GM$ in $x,y,z $

$\implies \displaystyle \frac{x+y+z}{3} \geq (xyz)^{1/3} \implies xyz = t\leq 8.$

$AM-GM$ in $xy,yz,zx $

$\implies \displaystyle \frac{xy+yz+zx}{3} \geq (xyz)^{2/3} \implies 2xyz-4\geq  3(xyz)^{2/3} \iff 2t-4 \geq 3t^{2/3}.$

Solving this inequality gives $t \geq 8$. Hence, $t=8$, so $xyz=8$ is the only solution.

Note that by direct inspection $x=y=z=2$ satisfy both equations and the constraint $t=8$, so this is the answer.

Comment: +1. Perhaps some readers should be told that we have equality $AM=GM$ in line 3 iff $x=y=z$, so $xyz=8\implies x=y=z=2.$

Comment: Thank You So much